# Alinhar o menu ao centro

Tags: html, css

Quero pedir ajuda para uma coisa que estou tentando há muito tempo. Não consigo, já vi vários posts e ninguém explica direito o que está errado ou o que devo fazer. Estou tentando alinhar um menu ao meio da página:

Código HTML:

```html
    <div id="menu">
        <header>
            <nav class="menu">  
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="br.html" target="_self"><img id="logo" src="br/_imagens/logo.png" alt="logo" onmousemove="mudaLogo()" onmouseout="mudaLogo2()"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/mac.html" target="_self">Mac</a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/ipad.html" target="_self">iPad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/iphone.html" target="_self">iPhone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/watch.html" target="_self">Watch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/tv.html" target="_self">TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="br/music.html" target="_self">Music</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Código CSS:

```
nav.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
nav.menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav.menu ul li{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
nav.menu ul li.menu{
    margin: -25px;
    padding: 0px;
}
nav.menu a{
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav.menu ul li:hover a{
    color: #A5A5A5;
}
```

Me ajudem pfv, estou tentando faz muito tempo.

Comment: Cntro Horizontal ou vertical, ou nos dois eixos?

Comment: Horizontal, lá em cima so que no meio da tela.

Comment: Eu não entendi porque você usou `nav.menu`. nav antes do menu significa o que?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use `float left`. Isso faz com que os elementos fiquem alinhados à esquerda. Retire o `margin: -25px` da logo. Resete margens e espaçamento da `ul`. Coloque `display: inline-block` nas li's e centralize com `text-align: center` na `ul`:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

nav.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
nav.menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
nav.menu ul li{
   display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
nav.menu ul li.menu{
    padding: 0px;
}
nav.menu a{
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav.menu ul li:hover a{
    color: #A5A5A5;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
     <header>
         <nav class="menu">  
             <ul>
                 <li class="menu"><a href="br.html" target="_self"><img id="logo" src="br/_imagens/logo.png" alt="logo" onmousemove="mudaLogo()" onmouseout="mudaLogo2()"></a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/mac.html" target="_self">Mac</a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/ipad.html" target="_self">iPad</a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/iphone.html" target="_self">iPhone</a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/watch.html" target="_self">Watch</a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/tv.html" target="_self">TV</a></li>
                 <li><a href="br/music.html" target="_self">Music</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
     </header>
 </div>
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso, obrigado pela dica do float: left.

Comment: Blz. Esses mouseover e mouseout na logo tb está ruim. Se isso for pra mudar a logo com o mouse, dá pra fazer de uma forma bem melhor. Se quiser te mostro um exemplo. Abs!

Comment: kk isso foi uma confusão minha também, é a mesma imagem só que a opacidade diminui um pouco(to refazendo o site da apple), tentei fazer com o hover mas fiz errado(percebi dps) eu achei que não funcionava com o hover e acabei tendo que fazer outra imagem com a opacidade meno e fiz esses eventos.

Comment: Isso vc faz no CSS, não precisa de JavaScript.

Comment: int, foi erro meu mesmo. Ainda estou aprendendo

Comment: Vc é novo no site. Dá uma olhada na página [tour] para saber mais um pouco o funcionamento do site.

Comment: funcionou valeu muito obrigado!

Comment: Cara, marque apenas 1 (apenas uma) das respostas, a que vc escolher, e não todas. Ao marcar mais de 1 vc desmarca a outra.

Comment: a, mas as duas fucionaram

Comment: Sim, mas só pode marcar 1, a que vc elegeu a melhor de todas.

Comment: Vc marcou a minha primeiro e depois marcou a outra. Assim a minha fica desmarcada.

Comment: Quando vc tiver 15 pontos de reputação vc pode votar nas setas em mais de uma resposta, mas marcar ✔ é só em uma.

Comment: ae certo entendi

Answer (score 0):

Na `UL` da `NAV` vc coloca `display:inline-block`, assim ela vai ficar apenas do tamanho do próprio conteúdo, tendo apenas o tamanho do próprio conteúdo e não a largura da tela inteira, vc consegue centraliza-la no meio da `NAV`, já que a `NAV` sim ocupa 100% da largura da tela. Depois disso na própria `NAV` vc coloca `text-align:center`. Como vc definiu a `UL` como `inline-block` ela pode receber propriedade como `text-align:center` vinda do *container* pai, no caso a `NAV`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center;
}
nav.menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav.menu ul li{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
nav.menu ul li.menu{
    margin: -25px;
    padding: 0px;
}
nav.menu a{
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav.menu ul li:hover a{
    color: #A5A5A5;
}

<body>
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <header>
        <nav class="menu">  
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href="br.html" target="_self"><img id="logo" src="br/_imagens/logo.png" alt="logo" onmousemove="mudaLogo()" onmouseout="mudaLogo2()"></a></li>
                <li><a href="br/mac.html" target="_self">Mac</a></li>
                <li><a href="br/ipad.html" target="_self">iPad</a></li>
                <li><a href="br/iphone.html" target="_self">iPhone</a></li>
                <li><a href="br/watch.html" target="_self">Watch</a></li>
                <li><a href="br/tv.html" target="_self">TV</a></li>
                <li><a href="br/music.html" target="_self">Music</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso.

Comment: @LuizFilipe tenta ai e se ficar com alguma dívida é só me dar um toque

Comment: Funcionou cara valeu muito obrigado, falou o que estava errado e ainda explicou o porque. Aonde tem a opção de dar mil estrelas?

Comment: @LuizFilipe fico feliz em ter ajudado. Basicamente quando um filho tem 100% da largura do pai vc não não consegue alinha-lo no contro, pois ele já ocupa toda a largura entende, pra centralizar o filho tem que ser menor ou maior que o pai. Abs

Comment: nossa, agora entendi mais ainda, é como se fosse uma caixa, se o objeto é do tamanho da caixa não tem como colocar do lado esquerdo ou direito. vlw!

Comment: @LuizFilipe exato é isso mesmo!